# Google charts: points on line graph not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

This should be a very quick answer but I've been playing around for an hour now and can't fix it. The points on my line graph aren't showing, when I inspect the point in dev tools I can see the fill-opacity is set to 0. If I manually set it to 1 it's visible but I cant find the option to set that in the script. Here's the code, what am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
          data.addColumn('number', 'New York');
          data.addColumn('number', 'London');

          data.addRows([
            ["Jan", 10, 12],
            ["Feb", 19, 31],
            ["Mar", 80, 20],
            ["Apr", 43, 56],
            ["May", 18, 42],
            ["Jun", 62, 81],
          ]);

          var options = {
            height: 400, 
            colors: ["#2980b9", "ffa22c"],
            pointSize: 10,
            dataOpacity: 1.0,
          };

          var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`google.charts.Line` is a reference to the newer Google Material Charts. From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Material):

> The Material Charts are in beta. The appearance and interactivity are largely final, but the way options are declared is not.

Unfortunately, you can't set some options yet, see this [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1922&q=material&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Modified%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary):

> The pointSize option is not yet supported for Material Charts.